# Is break needed if case is in parenthesis?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break)

I have this:

```
switch(i)
{
  case a:
  {
   //code
  }
  case b:
  {
   //code
  }
  case c:
  {
   //code
  }
}
```

If `i == a`, will the code in `b` and `c` be executed or must I put a `break;` in each one?

Thanks,

Comment: Geez, why all the -1's, yes, I can easily test this but I thought it would be useful for others.

Comment: @Milo:  I don't know about the down votes.  I did vote to close it just because there are other questions that seem to me to already cover this ground.  But the downvotes always puzzle me.

Comment: @Milo It says on the vote-down button "This question does not show any research effort; (...)". This is a question that can easily be tested, and thus doesn't show much research effort.

Comment: Come on, you can develop an example in 1 minute to test this....

Comment: The curly braces are redundant. You don't need to specify them.

Comment: @ Jared Sealey I need them if I want to create variables in the case.

Comment: See also: Duff's Device: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Comment: Braces: { }  Parentheses: ( )  Brackets: [ ]

Comment: @dave: no, the first pair of punctuators are called moustaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Must I put a `break;` in each one?

Yes, if you only want a single case to execute.  Alternatively, other control flow statements can also cause a `switch` to be exited, like `return` or `throw`.

If you were to replace `//code` with, say, `std::cout << "case [x]" << std::endl`, the answer would be readily apparent.

Answer (score 3):

yes, the breaks are needed for it to work correctly. The brackets only introduce a scope, they do not effect flow control.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the last one, even though it is good practice to do so.

If you don't put in `break` in one, then the current case and all continuing cases will execute until the next break, throw, or return.

This is useful in cases where you want two `case` sections to execute the same code, you can write:

```
case a:
case b:
   // ... some code...
   break;
```

Which would execute for both a and b.