# why Fall-Through by Default for Switch Statements?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break)

The interesting  phenomenon of most popular language [c, c++, java] is that switch  by default is fall-through.

I am curious about reason, does someone know this story?

Comment: I don't know the history, but if it weren't, there would be not difference between a switch block and an if-elseif block.

Comment: In future, please use the search function before asking a question that has already been asked many times before.

Comment: C# is a rather strange case - there is no possibility of fall-through, but you still need to specify a 'break' (or 'return', etc.).  So you need to explicitly state that there's no fall-through even though you can't have fall-through.

Answer (score 1):

In C the reason for this was the intention to make `switch` easily-opimizable into a jump table, Basically, based on the expression, the app will calculate the jump distance, jump to a certain point, and continue executing from that point.

I, however, think that this behavior is useful sometimes, because it helps to avoid code repetition in multiply `case`s, and after all it isn't hard to put the `break`s when you need it.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) has a decent example to illustrate how the fall-down can be utilized:

```
switch (n) {
  case 0:
    printf("You typed zero.");
    break;
  case 4:
    printf("n is an even number.");
  case 1:
  case 9:
    printf("n is a perfect square.");
    break;  
  case 2:
    printf("n is an even number.");
  case 3:
  case 5:
  case 7:
    printf("n is a prime number.");
    break;
  case 6:
  case 8:
    printf("n is an even number.");
    break;
  default:
    printf("Only single-digit numbers are allowed.");
}
```

Comment: An alternative design *could* have made break the default, and required an explicit fall-through. That would have save a lot of people from forgetting the break.

Comment: @Bo, yes, but if they used, say `continue` to force the fall-through, it would have been a little ambiguous. Like "where will it continue? Will it continue going through the cases, or will it continue the execution after the `switch`?" Though I agree that the way it works now isn't very intuitive either.