# c++ switch statement reverts to default statement after three recursive runs

Tags: c++

The purpose of my switch statement is to take an input of randomly generated input from 0 to 7 to preform on of the seven task. This is my code:

```
        switch(move)
    {
    case 0:
        //up
        movement = 1;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(0);
        }
        else 
        {   cout<<j<<"\t"<<x<<"\t"<<y+1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x,y+1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 1:
        //up-right
        movement = 2;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(1);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x+1<<"\t"<<y+1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x+1,y+1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        //right
        movement = 3;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(2);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x+1<<"\t"<<y<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x+1,y,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        //down-right
        movement = 4;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(3);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x+1<<"\t"<<y-1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x+1,y-1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 4:
        //down
        movement = 5;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(4);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x<<"\t"<<y-1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x,y-1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 5:
        //down-left
        movement = 6;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(5);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x-1<<"\t"<<y-1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x-1,y-1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 6:
        //left
        movement = 7;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(6);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x-1<<"\t"<<y<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x-1,y,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    case 7:
        //left-up
        movement = 8;
        next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np);
        //hit cell membrane
        if(next == 0)
        {
            move = vf.mv(7);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t"<<x-1<<"\t"<<y+1<<endl;
            virus[j].setvpoint(x-1,y+1,j,movement);
            break;
        }
    default:
            cout<<"Default"<<endl

    }
```

*next = vf.plv(x,y,movement,cp,np)* is a function that will output a 0 or a 1 depending on the x and y coordinates. The x and y coordinates are input into a distance formula to determine the distance from the center and if the distance is 13 or greater then next will equal 0. If it equals 0,  *move = vf.mv(7)* function will generate a new number from 0 to 7 that will then be put back into this switch function

The issue that I am having is that the switch function will recursively generate a new number 3 times and then revert to the default statement instead of continuing until it finds a distance less than 13. I have tried doing a do while loop and it still has not worked.

What should be my next step to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the heck aren't you putting your "break" statements at the end of the clause (just before the next "case"), instead of inside of an "else" block?!?

Comment: @paulsm4 Make an answer of that, as it's most likely the culprit.

Comment: I am putting breaks at the end of the else statement because I want the switch statement to reoccurring until the distance is less than 13. If I put it at the end of each case, then wont it not be recursive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break)

Comment: Learn about your debugger.  Especially learn about single-stepping through code, and displaying variable values between steps.

Answer (score 2):

Switch statements don't recurse.

Imagine your code (it's a rather large example), without any of the switch statement code. No `switch`, `case`, `break`, etc.

If you execute your code, all of it will execute, the entire block.

The `switch` statement allows you to execute a part of that block. The `case` statement chooses where to begin and the `break` statement chooses where to end. That's all.

Comment: i think the OP is confusing a switch with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `break` statements in the `if (next == 0)`, meaning execution continues to the next `case` clause. If you want to re-run the switch statement, you need to put it in a loop and put breaks correctly.

The only cases where can have no break statement at the very end of case are (1) you have a return there instead, and (2) you actually want the next case clause to execute as well.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate you taking the time to explain that to me!