# Understanding switch behaviour

Tags: java, switch-statement

Consider the following code

```
int x = 1
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
    default:
        System.out.println("no value found");
 }
```

it prints

```
1
2
no value found
```

as expected because there is no `break` in each case statement 
my doubt is that how execution goes to each case statement if there is no break in first one
because **x is not equal 2 then also its execute `case 2` block** 

but i understood `default` one because without `break` program continue its execution and execute the `default statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a remnant of the C programming language. In C `switch` is little more than a little syntactic sugar over a `goto` depending on the expression value and thus execution simply jumps to the appropriate `case` and continues from there. The labels in between are exactly that: labels. They are jump targets but don't affect control flow otherwise and from the compiler's point of view there is nothing in a label that merits a jump elsewhere (except there is INTERCAL's `COMEFROM` somewhere). So you have to put an explicit `break` after every case where you *don't* want to fall through to other options.

Java more or less inherited those semantics while eschewing some [of the crazier C idioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

C# on the other hand goes a bit further by disallowing fall-through entirely on non-empty `case` labels.

In my opinion though, this was a bit of a design error. Fall-through by default may be much easier to implement in the compiler (because you don't have to add a `goto` to the end of the `switch` and it aligns very nicely with how things actually work underneath), but in my experience there are vastly more programming errors by accidentally using fall-through than by accidentally *not* using it.

The most severe design error in my eyes is including the `switch` statement with all its weirdness in modern languages.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that are inherited from C++, execution naturally proceeds until the end of switch or a break. There is no test against cases as they are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is fall through. You need to add `break` before each next `case` unless you want that.

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("no value found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is an abstraction of a [branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table), and a branch table also has an implicit fall-through and requires an additional jump instruction to avoid it. Read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252733/1163607) as well.

As per [JLS 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> The body of a switch statement is known as a switch block.
>
> If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the expression, then we say that the case matches, and all statements after the matching case label in the **switch block**, if any, are executed in sequence.
>
> If all these statements complete normally, or if there are no statements after the matching case label, then the entire switch statement completes normally.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with how it's compiled and optimization.

It's why a switch is preferable to a bunch of chained if statements.

Answer (score 0):

From [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in
>   switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is not like an `if-then-else` statement. `switch` statement has multiple execution path.

The [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) states:

> Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch
>   block. The break statements are necessary because without them,
>   statements in switch blocks *fall through*: All statements after the
>   matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the
>   expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is
>   encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct behaviour. "default" doesn't mean all possible answers. It means all answers without these written in cases.

```
int x=1
switch(x)
    {
        default:
             System.out.println("no value found");
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
    }
```

will print

```
1
2
```

won't print

```
no value found
1
2
```

when using breaks; statements and default value there is called only one "branch" for each value

Answer (score 0):

**Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement**.  All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

You can use *if-then-else just, the overhead of testing is increases*..., which is avoided in switch-case, but break is necessary for proper execution...