# What are some interesting uses of 'switch' in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

The **switch** statement in C/C++ has an interesing feature that *all subsequent blocks will be executed if a condition is met*

For example,

```
int a = 2;
int b = a;
switch(b)
{
     case 1:cout<<1;
     case 2:cout<<2;
     case 3:cout<<3;
     case 4:cout<<4;
};
```

The above code will output **234** unless I put a *break* statement in case 2.

In 3 years(quite small,yeah) of my C/C++ programming experience, I have never encountered a problem where I had to use *switch* without putting *break* statments in every *case*. But judging by the fact that this feature has been stuck for so long, there might be some utility of it.

**Question:** What are some clever uses of *switch* statement as to utilize the above mentioned feature in C/C++?

Comment: I don't know what kind of clever uses you're looking for but you could read more on why `switch` requires `break` in this post: [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/252489/1798187). as stated in that post, you may use this "feature" for fall through.

Comment: There are "problems", where several values could need to be handled the same way. And this is very specific to the "problem". That's too broad, IMO.

Comment: Why this question is closed as primarily opinion based? I think its a valid question!

Comment: @user3414693 trying to find clever uses for some kind of `c++` ability is not really a standard `SO` question.

Comment: It really is not a standard SO question, but I won't classify it as based on opinion rather than facts. Maybe the word 'clever' misguides, but all I'm asking is uses for an apparent 'feature' in a programming language.
Yes, I would have trouble marking a single answer as correct.

Answer (score 7):

Probably one of the most interesting use cases I have seen would be [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) the case where you extend a scope within a *switch* over multiple *cases* which would look something like this:

```
void send( int *to, const int *from, int  count)
{
        int n = (count + 7) / 8;
        switch(count % 8) 
        {
            case 0: do {    *to = *from++;   // <- Scope start
            case 7:         *to = *from++;
            case 6:         *to = *from++;
            case 5:         *to = *from++;
            case 4:         *to = *from++;
            case 3:         *to = *from++;
            case 2:         *to = *from++;
            case 1:         *to = *from++;
                        } while(--n > 0);    // <- Scope end
        }
}
```

Comment: Boost Asio's stackless coroutines come pretty close to this (modulo evil pointer arith)

Comment: Unfortunately, using a `goto` (which is what a `switch` boils down to) to jump into a loop is likely to throw the optimizer way off track. This can be much more detrimental to performance than the gains of Duff's Device. So, while Duff's Device once were a good optimization when it was invented, I wouldn't use it in new code.

Answer (score 6):

This is usually used when you want to apply a similar action to a set of values. For instance, the following :

```
switch (event) {
   case DEVICE_DISCONNECTED:
   case CONNECTION_ERROR:
   case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
     transitionTo(disconnectedState);
     break;
   case CONNECTION_SUCCESS:
     transitionTo(connectedState);
     break;
}
```

is much more concise and readable in my opinion than :

```
switch (event) {
   case DEVICE_DISCONNECTED:
     transitionTo(disconnectedState);
     break;
   case CONNECTION_ERROR:
      transitionTo(disconnectedState);
     break;
   case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
     transitionTo(disconnectedState);
     break;
   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my current project, I have the following enumeration:

```
enum NodeType
{
  SCALAR, COMPOSITE, ARRAY, RESTRICTED_ARRAY
};
```

Thus, quite a few node-processing routines use this pattern:

```
switch (nodeType)
{
  case SCALAR:
    processScalar();
    break;
  case COMPOSITE:
    processComposite();
    break;
  case RESTRICTED_ARRAY:
    if (!handleRestrictions())
      return false;
    // continue to next case
  case ARRAY:
    processArray();
    break;
}
```

Note that it's almost necessary to *always* mark the lack-of-`break` as explicitly intended with a comment (like I did above) - future maintainers (including yourself in 3 months) will thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I've often used a construct to parse command line arguments like this:

```
switch (argument) {
    case arg_h:
    case arg__help:
    case arg_questionmark:
        printf("Help\n");
        break;
    case arg_f:
    case arg__file:
        //...
}
```

where argument is an enum type.

Comment: I've never thought of this, cool idea!

Comment: Ah! Yes. I needed something like this in a project. Thanks!