# My switch statement is not exiting the loop cleanly

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

I am currently testing out my driver program for my homework. What happens is that I have a menu printed with different options, and the program uses a switch statement based on the user's input to determine what to do. Everything works fine except for the "exit program" case, where it's supposed to leave the program and end it. Instead, it will print out the message "Quitting program" (like it's supposed to) and then follow up with doing one of the first 4 cases. It doesn't actually leave the switch statement. I don't know what could be wrong because I've used this method before and have not encountered this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "ListRecords.h"
#include "BookRecord.h"

using namespace std;

//Prints the menu for the user.
void printMenu(){
    cout << "\n\n1) Insert a book record into the list\n";
    cout << "2) Print information of a book with the given ISBN number\n";
    cout << "3) Print the list of books, sorted by ISBN (lowest to highest)\n";
    cout << "4) Print the list of books, sorted by title\n";
    cout << "5) Quit the program\n";
    cout << "Option: ";
}

//Menu block of the code. Takes in command choice and performs appropriate functions
void action(ListRecords books, int x){
    cin.sync();
    int option;
    switch (x){
        case 0: {
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        case 1: {
            string title, author, pub;
            long isbn;
            cout << "\n\t**Inserting a new book into the record**";
            cout << "\nTitle: ";
            getline(cin, title);
            cout << "Author: ";
            getline(cin, author);
            cout << "Publisher: ";
            getline(cin, pub);
            cout << "ISBN: ";
            cin >> isbn;
            BookRecord sample = BookRecord(title, author, pub, isbn);
            books.insertBookInfo(sample);
            cout << "\n\tNew book has been entered into the record\n\n";
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        case 2: {
            long printISBN;
            cout << "Printing book with ISBN number: ";
            cin >> printISBN;
            books.printBookInfo(printISBN);
            cout << "\n\n";
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        case 3: {
            cout << "\n\t**Printing all books in ISBN increasing order**\n";
            //books.quickSortNum(0, books.seeFillSize());
            books.rearrangeList(0);
            books.printAll();
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        case 4: {
            cout << "\n\t**Printing all books in alphabetical order**\n";
            //books.quickSortNum(0, books.seeFillSize());
            books.rearrangeList(1);
            books.printAll();
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        case 5: {
            cout << "\n\t**Quitting program. . .**\n";
            return;
                }
//For the purposes of debugging, I placed option 6 to print all books
        case 6: {
            books.printAll();
            printMenu();
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                }
        default:    {
            cout << "\n\t**ERROR: Invalid input. Try again**\nEnter option: ";
            cin >> option;
            action(books, option);
                    }

    }
}

int main(void){
    string fileName;
    int option;
//Prompt for file name
    cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << "\nLoading the file and its contents. . .";
//Create a List Records object and clear stream
    ListRecords books = ListRecords(fileName);
    cin.sync();     
    cout << "\n\n";
//Start menu process. Beginning option is 0
    action(books, 0);
//Once user quits, this will happen
    cout << "\n Thanks for trying out this program!\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you forgot a few `break` statements.

Comment: Hint: It's all about recursion.

Comment: C'mon pipples. `action` calls `action`. Do it 5 times and try quitting and you're still _in_ `action`.

Comment: Easiest way: Don't call action inside action. Return some kind of value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that your code uses recursion instead of iteration.

`main` makes a call to `action`, which goes into a `switch`, which then calls `action` again, which goes into the `switch` and calls `action`, until the Quit option is selected.

At this point the recursive call chain starts to unwind. Unfortunately, since your code lacks `break` statements, the `switch` is not exited immediately. Instead, the code falls through to the next `case` label, making you think that the `return` did not do its job at terminating the `action`. It did, but only the last action on the call stack is terminated. The remaining ones are still in progress, so they would continue as soon as the higher-level action finishes.

You can add `break` statements to your `switch` statement to mask the problem. However, the root cause would not go away: your program would remain poorly organized, and hard to read.

Consider rewriting the code using a `while` loop in the `action` function. Keep the `switch`, add `break`s, and remove recursive calls to `action` from inside the switch. Instead, let the loop continue, so that the `switch` is re-entered and processed again, until the Quit option is selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I used to do this in Java and never had that issue. I guess I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you do is call `action(books, 0);` to get to the menu.

```
switch (x){
    case 0: {
    printMenu();
    cin >> option;
    action(books, option);
}
```

There you call `action(books, option);` with the user supplied number.

You continue doing this for every option untill the user enters a `5` to end the program.
Because you don't have any `break` statements the code will go back to the 'calling case' and continue executing into the next `case`.

Be sure to end a `case` with a break to not continue executing the next `case` block (fall through).

Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break)n about why a break is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In main() you call `action(book, 0)` so it enters action function. Then you prompt for choice and enter action() gain with that option. Then you enter 5 and quit that action, the return address of the nested action() call returns just after that call, at case 1: block and continues to execute it.

So what you need to do is put `break` statement at the end of each block.

When you don't use `break` after once case block, the code continues executing next case block.

So as the guy above said, you should consider placing `break` at the end of each block.

Also, you might want to consider not using recursion, but maybe iteration, and put prompt block outside the switch/case.