# Switch statement with automatic break at each case step in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

If we want to have a switch statement where for each case we need to run some instructions then break we would so something like this:

```
switch (condition) {
   case (opt1):
      // do stuff
      break;
   case (opt2):
      // do stuff
      break;
   case (opt3):  
      // do stuff
      break;
   // ...
   default:
      // do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to have an exclusive switch, without fall through, where by default every option should break and not have to explicitly state the break instruction? And if not in C++ any idea if such a feature is available in other imperative languages?

Comment: There is no such flow control, as [switch statements were designed to allow fallthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break). You could use `if`/`else if`/`else` (at the expense of slight performance loss) if you want to avoid the `break`

Comment: To have that, you'd have to eliminate fall through, and why would you want to do that? It's too handy a feature.

Comment: I would probably want that type of derivate form of the swich statement in order to improve code readability and let's say row space. As an extended language feature.

Comment: @Vee6 `any idea if such a feature is available in other imperative languages?`   Pascal / Delphi

Answer (score 3):

C# needs the `break` too, but yells at you if you don't put it. You need to `goto label;` to explicitly fall through.

In C++, there is no way to do this natively (other than horrible macros, of course). However, Clang has the `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` warning. You can then insert `[[clang::fallthrough]];` to silence the warning for a deliberate fallthrough.

Documentation : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#fallthrough-clang-fallthrough

Answer (score 2):

I hate having break statements in my switches, so I use the pattern of wrapping a switch in a closure and returning from each case. For example:

```
auto result = [&] {
  switch(enum_val) {
    case A:
      return Foo();
    case B:
      return Bar();
  }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

"There is no automatic fall through" in Golang. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch