# Switch doesn't break automatically is on purpose?

Tags: c, switch-statement

The fact that switch doesn't break automatically after a case, is on purpose or accidentally. I thought it was on purpose, but a book (Expert C Programming) I have been reading (it's old) consider it as defeat.

> Perhaps the biggest defect in the switch statement is that cases don't break automatically after the
>   actions for a case label.

So, is it on purpose?

Comment: It was a choice. Some people disagree with the choice, e.g. the [tag:swift] programming language made the opposite choice.

Comment: My question was if that feature of switch (in C) was on purpose or not. It's not opinion-based.

Comment: @SimoneBonato Yet you select an answer that seems like an opinion.

Comment: @juanchopanza `it maybe wasn't such a good idea, after all (but that's opinion-based).` was the opinion.

Comment: "The decision was most probably made..." no facts here.

Comment: At least related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/252489/694576 if not a duplicate to the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decision was most probably made on purpose to be able to take advantage of case fall-through (there is not so much *coincidence* in language design).

Given that in real life fall through is nowadays considered bad programming practice by a lot of people and that the practical cases were you can really use it on purpose are very rare, it maybe wasn't such a good idea, after all (but that's opinion-based).

Comment: Yes, but remember C is probably the lowest of all high level programming languages, so rare cases are not so rare in C.

Comment: Hmm. I used to be writing gazillions of switch statements in my programming career - Maybe less than 0.5% of them were cases that could make *good use* of fall-through. About 99.9% of the cases where fall-through *was* involved though, were simply causes for hard-to-find bugs. Fall-through is a very special case and should maybe have had its own keyword to *enable* it rather than being the default.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. My statement was rather for general C and not this specific feature itself :)

Answer (score 5):

Many reasons its on purpose. Its great for menu driven text interfaces where you can place `a` right above `A` and allow the flow of control to pass through both. A more complex example is the [Duff device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to = *from++;
    case 7:      *to = *from++;
    case 6:      *to = *from++;
    case 5:      *to = *from++;
    case 4:      *to = *from++;
    case 3:      *to = *from++;
    case 2:      *to = *from++;
    case 1:      *to = *from++;
            } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=We%20analyzed%20the%20Sun%20C%20compiler%20sources%20to%20see%20how%20often%20the%20default%20fall%20through%20was%20used.&source=bl&ots=Hp88WhWF9Y&sig=1rvajAwTqUckDdemUTVVYxMavXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjoqojdjbjLAhWFtRoKHe2gC2EQ6AEIGzAA) also said:

> We analyzed the Sun C compiler sources
>   to see how often the default fall
>   through was used.  The Sun ANSI C
>   compiler front end has 244 switch
>   statements, each of which has an
>   average of seven cases.  Fall through
>   occurs in just 3% of all these cases.
>
> In other words, the normal switch
>   behavior is *wrong* 97% of the time.
>   It's not just in a compiler - on the
>   contrary, where fall through was used
>   in this analysis it was often for
>   situations that occur more frequently
>   in a compiler than in other software,
>   for instance, when compiling operators
>   that can have either one or two
>   operands:
>
> ```
> switch (operator->num_of_operands) {
>     case 2: process_operand( operator->operand_2);
>               /* FALLTHRU */
>
>     case 1: process_operand( operator->operand_1);
>     break;
> }
> ```
>
> Case fall through is so widely
>   recognized as a defect that there's
>   even a special comment convention,
>   shown above, that tells lint "this is
>   really one of those 3% of cases where
>   fall through was desired."

So it looks more of like it was done purposely.

Dennis Ritchie has written (in ACM HOPL-II):

> For example, the endcase that escapes from a BCPL switchon statement
>   was not present in the language when we learned it in the 1960s, and
>   so the overloading of the break keyword to escape from the B and C
>   switch statement owes to divergent evolution rather than conscious
>   change.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it on purpose?

Yes, it is.

Comment: Sounds very plausible. Do you happen to have a reference to back this up?

Comment: Would you really expect such a significant design details appears by accident? @juanchopanza

Comment: But you are correct, this isn't a very useful answer, which however might due to the question ... @juanchopanza